# Does anyone know why Python .sort() is not working as Intended?

Tags: python

This is just a simple python code to print out the divisors of a number.
First, it checks if the number can be divided by (x) and appends (x) and (number/x) to an empty list. It then sorts and converts the list to a set (to remove any duplicates)

```
import math

number = int(input("Enter a number : "))
divisors = list()
for x in range(1, math.ceil(math.sqrt(number))):
    if(number%x == 0):
        divisors.append(x)
        divisors.append(int(number/x))

divisors.sort()
print(set(divisors))
```

Output :

```
Enter a number : 56
{1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 14, 56, 28}

Enter a number : 60
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 60, 30}
```

It seems like the last two elements have been flipped.
I am still very much a beginner so go easy on me, thanks!.

Comment: Sets are unordered.

Comment: Just do `print(divisors)`. If you need to convert to a set to remove duplicates, do that before sorting (you will have to convert back to a list too).

Comment: If you want sorted unique list, you can do `print(sorted(list(set(divisors))))` instead

Comment: `sorted(list(...))` is superfluous, `sorted` accepts any iterable.

Comment: @Zwein The issue is that set are *unordered* so they don't enforce the order you are passing after sort :)

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting them first which gets them in the order you want but once you set(divisors) to remove the duplicates, it unorders them as sets are unordered.

A **set** is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

You need to change the last two lines.

```
divisors.sort()

print(set(divisors))
```

to

```
set(divisors)

divisors.sort()

print(divisors)
```